# If $f:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3\}$ is bijective and $f(1)=2$, can we verify that $f(2)=1$?

Tags: functions, inverse

I know that if $f$ is bijective, if $f(1)=2$ then $f^{-1}(2)=1$ but if $f:\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow\{1,2,3\}$ then does it mean necessarily that $f(2)=1$?

Comment: No....you could have $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=3$, $f(3)=1$.  That is bijective and satisfies $f(1)=2$.

Comment: I think you have some fundamental misconception of functions. Why do you think that $f(2)$ should be $1$? The only thing $f(1)=2$ prohibits for a bijective function is that $f(2)$ is also $2$, so if $X$ would be the set $\{1,2\}$ your reasoning would work.

Answer (score 1):

No, in general just because $f(1) = 2$, we don't have $f^{-1}(2) = 1$.  For example, let 
$$
f(1) = 2, f(2) = 2, f(3) = 1.
$$
Then $f^{-1}(2) = \{1,2\}$.  More properly we would write $f^{-1}(\{2\}) = \{1,2\}$.
Generally, for any set $A \subseteq X$, we have
$$
A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A)),
$$
and equality when $f$ is injective.

Comment: OP asked for a bijective function. Here $f(1)=2$ implies $f^{-1}(2)=1$